# Find out remaining values in enum comparing to array - Groovy

Tags: arraylist, groovy, enums

In groovy, I wrote following code:

```
enum ENVIRONMENT("test1, test2, test3, test4, test5")
```

I have an array with values `("test1, test2, test3")`

I have to compare the values in enum to values in arraylist .
I have to display all values in arraylist and if values are missing in arraylist`(like test4, test5)`, I have to show it some color

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by using `minus()` on `ArrayList`:

```
enum Environment {
    TEST1, TEST2, TEST3, TEST4, TEST5
}

List listToCompare = ['TEST1', 'TEST2', 'TEST3']

assert Environment.values()*.toString() - listToCompare == ['TEST4', 'TEST5']
```